# Android with java Pdf reader

Tags: android-2.2-froyo

i have been assigned with the android project to read the pdf File.Can any one suggest me about the open source available for this. i have tried vudroid. but it was not efficient.

Answer (score 0):

itexttopdf is good library that you can use

Comment: Is there any open source code available to read pdf files in android